# Styling select and options in html (IE 6)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, select

I want to stlye a select element. i.e to constrain its width to a specified value,background-color.
I also want to be able to style the option set(via Option constructor)

Is it possible. I am using IE6.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note.  Because IE6 renders the drop down box using Windows Shell ListBox and Combobox controls, many styling features do not work.  I wish I could find an old link out ther for you but I cant seem to find it.  I belive background-color will not work, I know border color does not work in ie 6.

Here is the best link I could find. It explains some but not all

[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2006/01/17/514076.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20151112172907/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ie/archive/2006/01/17/514076.aspx)